# Why do all my 'Forwarders' tabs only list the domain's domain controllers?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have recently created two new domain controllers in my network, running Windows Server 2008R2.   There were two domain controllers already on the network (Windows Server 2003)

In the new domain controllers my 'Forwarders' tab in DNS lists the ip address of the two 2003 DCs.  In the forwarders tab of those it says 'All other DNS Domains'

Aren't the forwarders supposed to only list external/isp DNS servers?

Is there a reason why a domain might list its own domain controllers and nothing else int he forwarders tab?

There have been no problems resolving external addresses despite none of my domains having external DNS servers in their forwarders list.

Comment: I've seen this before in several larger organizations that I've done work for. The reason being that only specific, highly secured DNS servers are permitted to send DNS queries outside of the internal network. All other DNS servers then query these servers. It seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to me.

Comment: Ok so,  maybe my predecessor took a dc offline that was one of these dcs permitted to send queries outside, but never passed the job onto the remaining dcs, and now my domain is using the root hints to process external queries?

Comment: Yes. That's the default behavior for Windows DNS. If you don't need to use specific forwarders then just remove them and let each DNS server use the root hints for external lookups.